# Problems with Clojurescript quickstart -- build fails

Tags: clojurescript

I'm trying to follow the [Clojurescript Quick-Start](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Quick-Start)

I have downloaded the Clojurescript jar as described in the Quick-Start guide. I have verified that it has the appropriate size (about 19M). I have created the files. But when I try to build using the command:

```
java -cp cljs.jar:src clojure.main build.clj
```

Java returns the following stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate cls/build/api__init.class or cls/build/api.clj on classpath., compiling:(/Users/jnedzel/Documents/prj/closurescript/quickstart/hello_world/build.clj:1:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7249)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7175)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invoke(main.clj:275)
    at clojure.main$script_opt.invoke(main.clj:337)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:421)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:379)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate cls/build/api__init.class or cls/build/api.clj on classpath.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you have `cls.build.api` instead of `cljs.build.api` in build.clj?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: There's a typo in *build.clj*

### Full explanation

As of the Quick-Start, the file *build.clj* should have the following content:

```
(require 'cljs.build.api)

(cljs.build.api/build "src" {:output-to "out/main.js"})
```

The error message says `Could not locate cls/build/api__init.class`. When the clojure compiler compiles a ns, a loader classfile is generated with the name *my/domain/lib__init.class*. That's the class that will be loaded given `(require 'my.domain.lib)`.

In the case of `cljs.build.api`, that would be ***cljs**/build/api__init.class*. But it is trying to load ***cls**/build/api__init.class* instead, so you have a typo there.